# 401: Sorry, your credentials are not valid for this resource

Tags: coverity

When i click view defect button, i'm getting this page error:

401: Unauthorized
Sorry, your credentials are not valid for this resource.
[image: 401]

I'm sign in with my github account. So my coverity email and github email is same.  But still i can't look my defects.

Note: I'm owner of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by contacting the coverity scan mail address. it's a systemic problem.

mail: scan-admin@coverity.com